# how to implement SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 in a query?

Tags: php, mysql

im having a problem with a query that gives this error

Message:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1104 The SELECT would examine more than MAX_JOIN_SIZE rows; check your WHERE and use SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 or SET MAX_JOIN_SIZE=# if the SELECT is okay

But i dont really know how to set the sql_big_select into the query (or other place)

the code

```
public static function getItems( $orderBy, $limit = null, $term_id = null ) 
{
    $query  = ' SELECT definitions.*, terms.term, COUNT(DISTINCT(likes.id)) AS likes, COUNT(DISTINCT(dislikes.id)) AS dislikes, 
               CASE WHEN COUNT(voted.id) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS voted, 
               GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(tags.name) SEPARATOR ",") AS tags ';
    // Select all the definition information, and count the likes and dislike records
    // Get whether the user has voted also
    $query .= 'FROM definitions ';
    // From definitions

    $query .= 'INNER JOIN terms ON terms.id = definitions.term_id ';

    $query .= 'LEFT JOIN votes AS likes ON definitions.id = likes.definition_id AND likes.score = 1 ';
    // Join on the votes table by likes
    $query .= 'LEFT JOIN votes AS dislikes ON definitions.id = dislikes.definition_id AND dislikes.score = -1 ';
    // Join on the votes table again, but by dislikes
    $query .= 'LEFT JOIN votes AS voted ON definitions.id = voted.definition_id AND voted.ip = ? ';
    // Join on the votes table again, but for voting

    $query .= 'LEFT JOIN definition_tag ON definitions.id = definition_tag.definition_id ';
    $query .= 'LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id = definition_tag.tag_id ';
    // Join on the tags table



    $query .= 'WHERE approved = 1 ';
    // Only get approved definitions matching the term

    if ( ! is_null( $term_id ) ) 
    {
        $query .= 'AND definitions.term_id = ? ';
    }

    $query .= 'GROUP BY definitions.id ';
    // Group by the definition id
    $query .= 'ORDER BY '.$orderBy;
    // And order by highest likes

    if ( ! is_null( $limit ) ) $query .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    // Add the limit

    $bindings = array( 

        Request::ip()

    );

    if ( ! is_null( $term_id ) ) 
    {
        $bindings[1] = $term_id;

    }

    return DB::query($query, $bindings);
}
```

Comment: add a query before with the recommended `SET statement` and execute it.

Comment: thanks for the answer. if i understand ok it will be like? $query .= 'SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 ';  ?

Comment: Maybe you're only able to set the session variable: `SET @@SQL_BIG_SELECTS = 1;`

Comment: tried       $query  = ' SET SESSION SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1 SELECT definitions.*, terms.term, COUNT(DISTINCT(likes.id)) AS likes, COUNT(DISTINCT(dislikes.id)) AS dislikes, .... but it didnt work :S

Comment: You've got to execute two single statements or use a multi_query() method like [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)